# $f(g(x)) = x$ find p

Tags: functions

> Given :
>
> $f(x) = \frac{3x +1}{2x+1}$
>
> $g(x)=\frac{3p+1}{2x-3}$
>
> $f(g(x)) = x$

Problem :
find p

Attempt :

$f(g(x)) = x$

Substitute $ x$ in $f(x) $ into $ g(x)$

I get $ (2x-3)(2x+1) = 3p+2 $

What should I do next?

Comment: If your calculation is right, then $p$ does not exist, since $(2x-3)(2x+1)=3p+2$ cannot hold for every $x$.

Comment: My calculation was wrong. But now i get the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$ implies that $x\left(2g\left(x\right)+1\right)=3g\left(x\right)+1$
or equivalently that $g\left(x\right)=\frac{1-x}{2x-3}$.

Combining that with $g\left(x\right)=\frac{3p+1}{2x-3}$ we find that
$p=-\frac{1}{3}x$.

The request to find $p$ indicates that $p$ is a constant and if
that is the case then no solution exists.

It might be that $p$ is allowed to be function of $x$ and in that case $p(x)=-\frac13x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$f(g(x)) = x$$
$$\implies g(x) = f^{-1}(x)$$

So you need to find $f^{-1}(x)$ and compare with $g(x)$ to find $p$.

Comment: Please answer the stated question, (the OP also has an idea how to work), or provide a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer $p=-x/3$**

Find $f^{-1}(x)$ from $y=\frac{3x+1}{2x+1}$ get $x=\frac{1-y}{2y-3}$. So $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{1-x}{2x-3}.$ Comparing it with $g(x)$ which is nothing but $f^{-1}(x)$, you get $p=-x/3.$

**Your way**

$$f(g(x))=\frac{3 \frac{3p+1}{2x-3}+1}{ 2 \frac{3p+1}{2x-3}+1}=x\Rightarrow 2x^2-3x+6px-9p=0 \Rightarrow (x+3p)(2x-3)=0$$
We get $p=-x/3$ for every $x$.

Comment: The answer is -1

Comment: @dan_fulea Yes, I understand your concern I have added another part in my answer.

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Sorry, the answer cannot be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$
f(g(x)) = f\left( \frac{3p+1}{2x-3} \right),
$$
but
$$
f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{2x+1}.
$$

Can you calculate the value of $f(g(x))$? Once you have done that, use $f(g(x))=x$ and solve for $p$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes i did that. But can't solve p. (2x-3)(2x+1)=3p+2

Comment: @Klangen: Can you take it from here? We have two Möbius transformations for the matrices $$F = \begin{bmatrix}3&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\ ,\qquad G = \begin{bmatrix}0&2p+1\\2&-3\end{bmatrix}\ ,$$ and the problem claims $FG$ corresponds to the identity Möbius transform.